# Getting the request object outside a mod_perl handler

Tags: apache, perl, apache2, mod-perl

I want to log to the Apache log file from a subroutine that is called from a mod_perl handler but doesn't have the request object ($r) .

```
sub handler {
    my ($r) = shift;
    ...
    Common::subroutine_that_also_logs();
    ...
}

package Common;
sub subroutine_that_also_logs {
    ...
    # $r->log->info('cannot do this')
    ...
}
```

While using `print STDERR` or `warn` works but I want to use Apache2::Log to get additional request information in the log :-

```
[Fri May 30 16:12:37 2014] [info] [client 123.123.123.123] cannot do this
```

instead of just

```
cannot do this
```

I want to avoid a global init in the handler as that would mean updating a few hundred handlers :-

```
my $globalr;
sub handler {
    $globalr = shift;
    ...
    Common::subroutine_that_also_logs();
}

package Common;
sub subroutine_that_also_logs {
    ...
    $globalr->log->info('can try this')
    ...
}
```

I have set up a single `PerlFixupHandler` for initializing `$globalr` but I wonder if there is a better way or if `$r` is available directly by other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Apache2::RequestUtil`.

```
package Common;
use Apache2::RequestRec;
use Apache2::RequestUtil;

sub subroutine_that_also_logs {
    my $r = Apache2::RequestUtil->request;
    # some process you want using $r
}
```

If this phase is PerlFixupHandler, `$r` has whole request information e.g. MIME-type and so on.

If you use this method, you have to write `PerlOptions +GlobalRequest` on your `httpd.conf` Apache httpd config file.

Please see `perldoc Apache2::RequestUtil` for detail.